# Скрыть динамический блок при нажатии вне его области

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок `div` который появляется при нажатии на другой блок `div`, нужно сделать так что бы при нажатии вне области этого блока он скрывался, делал так:

```
$('.in20 .hid').click(function() {
  var check = $(this).siblings('.hid-content').is(':visible')
  $('.in20 .in19 .hid-content').each(function() {
    $(this).hide()
  })
  if (!check) {
    $(this).siblings('.hid-content').show();
  } else {
    return true;

  }
  var check1 = $(this).siblings('.hid-content').is(':visible')
  if (check1) {
    $('body').on('click', function() {
      $('.hid-content').hide();

    })
  }
});
```

Суть в том что при клике по `body` не срабатывает `.show` который отображает блок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно повесить `.mouseup` событие на документ и проверять является ли целью наш блок.

```js
$(document).mouseup(e => {
  let ourBlock = $('#our-block');
  if (!ourBlock.is(e.target) && ourBlock.has(e.target).length === 0)
      ourBlock.hide()
})
```

```css
#our-block {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
}

#our-sub-block {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="our-block">
  <div id="our-sub-block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Все работает, за исключением клика по блоку, теперь он исчезает, так как у него высота формируется исходя из размера содержимого блока(в данном случае <label>)... То есть при клике по <label> блок исчезает, что не очень хорошо

Comment: @ilyaaa521 приношу извинения, забыл про дочерние элементы. Правил код, проверьте

Comment: Все работает! Спасибо большое

Comment: Хорошего дня. ;)

Comment: И вам хорошего дня ;)

Comment: А при чем тут `mouseup` и почему все это не повесить на `click`?